# FTP user can't log in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

i made a shell script, that should add a user:

```
useradd $1 --password $2 --create-home --shell /bin/false --system
```

This user should only log into FTP, and should not log into SSH or anything else. But the problem is, that right now this user can neither log into FTP, nor SSH. I added **/bin/false** to **/etc/shells**.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying loggin with /bin/false and then ... nothing. Is Because false stands for "...does nothing except return an exit status of 1, meaning failure." ([false invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/false-invocation.html#false-invocation)

First, i think you just already have installed the *vsftpd* package.

The way to create an user account to be able to log in in the FTP server and not log into SSH or anything else should be (in Ubuntu):

```
# useradd -m user -s /usr/sbin/nologin

# passwd user
```

and then add the line to the end of the */etc/shells* file

```
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

[ubuntu ftp server installation and configuration](https://www.1and1.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/ubuntu-ftp-server-installation-and-configuration/)

Adapt this to your needs in your script.

To complete the answer follow this script adapted to yours needs (the original script can be found [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
    read -p "Enter username : " username
    read -s -p "Enter password : " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$username exists!"
        exit 1
    else
        pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
        useradd -m --shell /usr/sbin/nologin --system -p $pass $username
        [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
    fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi
```

Save it like "adduser.txt"

Then

```
$ chmod 755 adduser.txt

$ sudo bash ./adduser.txt
```

Will ask you to enter *username* and *password*.

control if the user was created (username: user)

*$ cat /etc/passwd | grep user*

Then you just have to login in FTP with the new user.

PS: Sorry for my rusty english.

Comment: still not working... i tried this before :( could my script be wrong?
i'm using pure-ftpd

Comment: Had you tunned the file vsftpd.conf in /etc to your needs? If you you follow the manual that i linked i'm pretty sure you will make chess-mate ;)

Comment: but i'm using debian

Comment: local_enable=YES in vsftpd.conf file is uncomment?

Comment: yes, it's not commented

Comment: Is your script who don't create the user? or you can create the user with your script and then can't login into FTP?

Comment: my script creates the user but can't log in with FTP.

Comment: In etc/passwd the user created have the shell /usr/sbin/nologin? I just runned some test on a debian VMachine and works for me. Would you like that i improve the answer with one old the script that i used for create the user who only can login in FTP and nothing else? Firewall?

Comment: my script adds the user, and when i check /etc/passwd it has the shell /usr/sbin/nologin. But when i create an user by "adduser", and set it's shell later in /etc/passwd, it works, and can log in with FTP. But my script created user can't log in with FTP.